# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories error using DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to download update.apk from my server and install the app using downloadManager and save it to the app's default folder. Which is inside Android/data/com.sn.myapp/files/

So I tried this:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
                request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
                request.setTitle("App Update");
                request.setDescription("Downloading... ");
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
                String PATH = Objects.requireNonNull(getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(PATH, "/" + "update" + ".apk");
```

And to install the app:

```
try {

        String PATH = Objects.requireNonNull(getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(PATH + "/update.apk");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            Uri downloaded_apk = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            intent.setDataAndType(downloaded_apk, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                mContext.grantUriPermission(mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", downloaded_apk, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I execute the above I get the following error:

```
2021-05-17 13:23:05.488 9432-9432/com.sn.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sn.myapp, PID: 9432
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.sn.myapp/files
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2381)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:755)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:613)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:601)
        at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:576)
        at com.sn.myapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7520)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7489)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:826)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28555)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

What could be wrong?

Instead of the above if I use the below code:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/myApp/"  + "/" + "update" + ".apk");
```

The file gets downloaded but I get the following error when accessing the file to install.

```
2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /Download/myApp/update.apk
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at com.sn.myapp.MainActivity.installApk(MainActivity.java:196)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at com.sn.myapp.MainActivity.access$400(MainActivity.java:33)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at com.sn.myapp.MainActivity$2.onReceive(MainActivity.java:181)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1566)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.428 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.440 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@8e0e98b[MainActivity]
    2021-05-17 13:47:54.441 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: windowFocusChanged hasFocus=true inTouchMode=true
    2021-05-17 13:48:18.711 9434-17078/com.sn.myapp W/DisplayEventDispatcher: dispatcher 0xb400006f92614f50 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
    2021-05-17 13:48:18.711 9434-9434/com.sn.myapp W/DisplayEventDispatcher: dispatcher 0xb400006f426157d0 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x6d746f6e
```

Comment: The second is ok. But setting for provider need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Combine

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

or

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir("myfolder")
getExternalFilesDir("myfolder");
```

You were mixing them up and used a full path as parameter which will not go.

But... for the first combination you better register a broadcast receiver for action download complete and use the uri the download manager will give you then to serve the file.